# Set IIS7 to default all new app pool to 64 bit

Tags: iis-7.5

Is there a setting in IIS 7.5 to default the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to False on newly created app pools? I know how to set it for one app pool in power shell, but I'm wondering if there's a global IIS setting for this so it will always be false when a new one is created. Thanks!

Comment: False is the default.  Are yours getting set to true then?

Comment: Yes, on one of our servers all new app pools are getting set to true by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The default value for "Enable 32-Bit Applications" is "False" by default.* If that is not the case in your setup, you can "fix" it using any of these methods:

**Using GUI tool:**

IIS Manager | Application Pools | Right click | Set Application Pool Defaults...

**Using command line (appcmd.exe in this particular case):**

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:"False" /commit:apphost
```